# Recuperar objeto instanciado em outro arquivo no PHP

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, pdo

Pergunta rápida: como recuperar a instância de um objeto criada em um arquivo diferente em uma aplicação PHP?

Pergunta completa: Eu estou criando um projeto para estudos em PHP onde eu tenho o arquivo `conn.php` que contém a instância PDO para a conexão com o banco de dados. Um outro arquivo chamado `functions.php` contém a função `getAllUsers()` que deve realizar a consulta no banco e retornar os resultados.

Usando apenas o `require('conn/conn.php')` não recuperaria a instância do objeto criado no arquivo? Se não, como poderia conseguir isso?

Agradeço desde já toda a atenção!

O código dos arquivos `conn.php` e `functions.php` seguem abaixo:

**conn.php**

```
<?php

/*
** Arquivo de conexão com o banco de dados
** Quaisquer alterão irá impactar na aplicação inteira
*/

require('config.php');

// Função de conexão com o banco de dados
function databaseStartConnection() {

    $dsn = DBBRAND . ":dbname=" . DBNAME . ";host=" . DBHOST;

    // Tente se conectar ao banco com as crendenciais fornecidas
    try {
        $pdo = new PDO($dsn, DBUSER, DBPASS);

    } catch (PDOException $e) {

        // Em caso de erro, exiba a mensagem e encerre a aplicação
        echo "<p><b>Erro de conexão com o banco de dados: </b>" . $e->getMessage() . "</p><br>";
        die();
    }   
}
```

**functions.php**

```
<?php

/* 
** Realiza consulta teste
** Modificar este arquivo para a consulta real
*/

require('conn/conn.php');

// Inicia conexão com o banco de dados
databaseStartConnection();

// Recupera do banco todos os usuários
function getAllUsers($pdo = $this->$pdo) { // Recuperar o objeto criado no arquivo conn.php

    // Consulta vai aqui

}

// Fecha conexão com o banco de dados
databaseCloseConnection();
```

Comment: OO em PHP raramente é coisa boa. PHP quase sempre é usado em situações onde não há preservação de estado, e OO está ligada diretamente a manutenção de estado. Tem como fazer serialização e deserialização de objetos, mas geralmente é pior ainda. De qq forma, no seu exemplo dado, não tem razão nenhuma para usar nadinha de OO. Mesmo que infelizmente algo te obrigue a usar PDO, reconectar a cada script é o que se faz normalmente. E o fato de usar sintaxe de OO não impede de pensar proceduralmente.

Comment: Entendi. Mas de qualquer forma eu gostaria de manter as minhas funções de consulta no banco dentro do arquivo `functions.php` e a minha conexão dentro do `conn.php`. Eu não consigo pensar neste momento uma outra forma viável para fazer isso. Fazer tudo dentro do mesmo arquivo ficaria muito desorganizado.

Comment: Sim, é conveniente manter assim, mas perceba que isso não tem nada a ver com precisar da primeira instância criada. O fato de usar um "new"  não significa que vc deva se apegar àquela instância. Cada vez que algo incluir aquele script, será criada uma instância e descartada ao final.

Comment: Certo, dentro da minha função `getAllUsers()` eu não precisaria ter estabelecido a conexão com o meu banco, com as credenciais passadas dentro do meu arquivo `conn.php`? Ou eu precisaria criar uma nova conexão para cada função que eu criar? Acho que assim não ficaria muito prático.

Comment: Muita  calma nessa hora kkkk. Perceba que nao estamos falando mais nada de OO. O normal em PHP quando usado em scripts rápidos (paginas web) é você abrir a conexao 1 vez só no começo do script, guardar numa variável, e usar durante a vida do script. Se vai ser no próprio script ou se vai incluir no começo, é questão de organização de código. Normalmente se faz  um require_once no começo pra isso. Novamente,  isso independe do paradigma que vá usar. Seja um `$var = new PDO(...);` ou `$var = mysqli_connect(...);` a idéia é a mesma, fazer 1x no começo e usar a variável durante o script.

Comment: O fato dela ser uma instância de objeto ou um ponteiro para uma conexão é detalhe, considerando o tempo curtissimo de vida do script.

Comment: @Bacco Consegui resolver usando um `return` na minha variável `$pdo` e recuperando a instância no arquivo `functions.php`  atribuindo a uma nova variável o valor deste `return`. Eu vou editar a minha pergunta com o novo código caso você queira dar uma olhada. O problema é que agora eu não consigo chamar a função `getAllUsers()` na minha 'view' sem ter que passar um parâmetro.. Vou pensar em como vou resolver isso ainda, mas muito obrigado pela sua atenção.

Answer (score -1):

Consegui resolver criando um return dentro da minha função `databaseStartConnection()` e recuperando seu valor dentro da mo meu arquivo `functions.php`, conforme pode ser visto no código a seguir.

**Função `databaseStartConnection()` dentro do arquivo conn.php**

```
function databaseStartConnection() {

    $dsn = DBBRAND . ":dbname=" . DBNAME . ";host=" . DBHOST;
    $dbUser = DBUSER;
    $dbPass = DBPASS;

    // Tente se conectar ao banco com as crendenciais fornecidas
    try {
        $conn = new PDO($dsn, $dbUser, $dbPass);
        return $conn;

    } catch (PDOException $e) {

        // Em caso de erro, exiba a mensagem e encerre a aplicação
        echo "<p><b>Erro de conexão com o banco de dados: </b>" . $e->getMessage() . "</p><br>";
        die();
    }   
}
```

**Função `getAllUsers()` dentro do arquivo `functions.php` recebendo $conn como parâmetro**

```
$conn = databaseStartConnection();

// Recupera do banco todos os usuários
function getAllUsers($conn) { 

    if(isset($conn)) {
        $v = "TRUE";
    } else {
        $v = "FALSE";
    }

    return $v;
}

echo getAllUsers($conn);
```

Resposta no navegador

> TRUE

Comment: Só de curiosidade, lembre-se que não precisa estar numa function o código da conexão, aí a variável estará disponível no escopo principal. Adicionalmente, o PHP tem como forçar uso de variávels globais dentro de funções, mas sinceramente recomendo evitar, raramente é a solução correta. Não vou dizer que nunca pode usar (até pq se for purista a esse ponto, já nem devia usar PHP) mas é um hábito que geralmente acaba gerando dor de cabeça,principalmente quando o projeto aumenta.